# jquery change parent html of appended element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help to adjust the code:

```
$('parent').click(function(){
    $(this).html('<button> child <button/>');

    $('button').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().html('some new html');
    });
});
```

I am trying to create the dynamic action conformation with jQuery. For example user clicks DELETE (parent). DELETE then is changed to YES / NO (child button). User clicks NO and parent html is becoming DELETE again.

Comment: Wouldnt it be easier to use jquery ui and its modal function? I think thats what youre asking for, and its already optimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try delegated event handlers like

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function () {
    $(this).replaceWith($('<span />', {
        html: '<button class="yes">Yes</button><button class="no">No</button>'
    }))
})
$(document).on('click', '.no', function () {
    $(this).parent().replaceWith($('<button />', {
        text: 'Delete',
        'class': 'delete'
    }))
})
$(document).on('click', '.yes', function () {
    console.log('delete')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QetBZ/)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new jQuery element and then append this, you can then assign the click handler to only that element.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nunners/ymRRn/)

```
$('#parent').click(function(){
    var yesBtn = $('<button type="button">Yes</button>');
    var noBtn = $('<button type="button">No</button>');        

    $(this).html('');
    $(this).append(yesBtn);
    $(this).append(noBtn);

    $(yesBtn).click(function(){
        event.stopPropagation();
        // On yes event handler
        $(this).parent().html('You clicked Yes!');
    });

    $(noBtn).click(function(){
        event.stopPropagation();
        // On no event handler
        $(this).parent().html('You clicked No!');
    });
});
```

Not the `event.stopPropagation();` in the child click handlers, this will stop the event bubbling up the DOM tree and re-executing the initial `parent` click.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use the JavaScript confirm popup box? That way you don't need to edit the DOM at all and lives are made easier :).

```
    $('parent').click(function(){
       var blnDelete = confirm("Do you want to delete?");
       if (blnDelete) {
         // Delete
       } else {
         // Don't Delete
       }
    });
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp

Comment: because i'am a perfectionist and conformation dialog popping up right where you just clicked is cooler :)

Comment: Then I suggest following what @WreithKassan said and use JQuery UI's Dialog function: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation